# Acessar dados de uma estrutura JSON

Tags: python, json

Estou com alguns problemas ao tentar acessar alguns dados em uma estrutura JSON.

O código JSON é esse:

```
[
    {
        "teste":[
            {
                "dados":"teste",
                "uno":[
                    {
                        "um":"Teste",
                        "cores":[
                            {
                                "preto":"Preto",
                                "branco":"Branco"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Como eu dou o `print` de apenas um destes dados? Por exemplo, gostaria de acessar somente o conteúdo contido em `"preto"` pelo programa escrito em Python. Ou então acessar apenas o que está contido dentro de `"dados"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As outras respostas já deram o código que faz o que você precisa. Mas apenas para complementar, acho importante você entender o formato de um JSON, assim conseguirá trabalhar melhor com quaisquer dados futuramente.

A sintaxe de um JSON pode ser consultada [aqui](http://json.org/). **De maneira bem resumida**, podemos dividir os tipos de dados em:

- valores "básicos": números, strings, booleanos
- arrays: uma lista ordenada de valores
- objetos: um conjunto de pares "chave: valor" (sem ordem definida)

As chaves de um objeto são strings, e o valor pode ser qualquer um dos definidos acima (um número, uma string, um array ou outro objeto).
Os valores de um array podem ser também qualquer um (número, string, objetos, outro array).

Um array é delimitado por colchetes (`[` e `]`): tudo que está dentro dos colchetes são elementos do array, e eles ficam separados por vírgula. Então `[1, "abc", 2]` é um array com 3 elementos (o número 1, a string `"abc"` e o número 2, nesta ordem).

Um objeto é delimitado por `{` e `}`, e os pares "chave: valor" são separados por vírgula. Então `{ "nome" : "Fulano", "idade": 30 }` é um objeto que possui a chave `"nome"`, cujo valor é a string `"Fulano"`, e a chave `"idade"`, cujo valor é o número 30.

O detalhe é que - como já dito acima - os valores dentro de um array ou objeto podem ser outros arrays e objetos. Exemplos:

```js
[10, { "nome": "Fulano", "idade": 30} ]
```

O exemplo acima é um array com 2 elementos: número 10 e um objeto com as chaves `"nome"` e `"idade"`.

---

```js
{ "nome": "Fulano", "idade": 30, "filmes_preferidos": [ "Star Wars", "Clube da Luta" ] }
```

O exemplo acima é um objeto com 3 chaves: `"nome"` (cujo valor é a string `"Fulano"`), `"idade"` (cujo valor é o número 30) e `"filmes_preferidos"` (cujo valor é um array contendo duas strings: `"Star Wars"` e `"Clube da Luta"`).

Não há um limite teórico para o aninhamento destas estruturas (talvez apenas [limites práticos dependentes da implementação](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#implementation-limitations)). Podemos ter um array contendo objetos, que por sua vez contém arrays, que contém outros objetos, que podem conter mais objetos e assim por diante.

---

No seu caso, temos:

```
[ <-- início do array
    { <-- primeiro elemento do array é um objeto
        "teste":[   <- chave "teste", cujo valor é um array
            {       <- dentro deste array temos outro objeto
                "dados":"teste",  <- chave "dados", valor "teste"
                "uno":[           <- chave "uno", valor é um array
                    {                 <- dentro deste array, temos outro objeto
                        "um":"Teste",   <- chave "um", valor "Teste"
                        "cores":[       <- chave "cores", valor é um array
                            {             <- dentro deste array, temos outro objeto
                                "preto":"Preto",   <- chave "preto", valor "Preto"
                                "branco":"Branco"  <- chave "branco", valor "Branco"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Ou seja, é um array que tem um objeto, cuja única chave tem outro array, que tem outro objeto, que tem uma chave que contém outro array, que por sua vez tem outro objeto, com outro array contendo mais um objeto.

Sem entrar no mérito desta estrutura ser bem complexa (e sem mais contexto não dá para dizer se ela é adequada ou não), várias linguagens possuem APIs para manipular dados no formato JSON e transformá-los em estruturas da própria linguagem.

No caso do Python, o [módulo `json`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) faz a conversão usando [esta tabela](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json-to-py-table):

| JSON | Python |
| --- | --- |
| object | dict |
| array | list |
| string | str |
| number (int) | int |
| number (real) | float |
| true | True |
| false | False |
| null | None |

Usando a mesma solução das outras respostas, você pode fazer o *parsing* de uma string contendo um JSON usando o [método `loads`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.loads):

```py
import json

JSON = """[
{
    "teste":[
        {
            "dados":"teste",
            "uno":[
                {
                    "um":"Teste",
                    "cores":[
                        {
                            "preto":"Preto",
                            "branco":"Branco"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
]"""

dados = json.loads(JSON)
```

Seguindo a tabela acima, `dados` será mapeado para um [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#list) (já que o JSON original é um array). Como este array só possui um elemento (que é um objeto), então `dados[0]` (o primeiro elemento da lista) será um [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Este objeto, por sua vez, possui a chave `"teste"`, cujo valor pode ser acessado com `dados[0]['teste']` - e este, por sua vez, é outro array, que possui um único elemento: o objeto que possui as chaves `"dados"` e `"uno"` (e para obtê-lo, basta pegar o primeiro elemento da lista: `dados[0]['teste'][0]`).

Em seguida podemos pegar cada uma das chaves com `dados[0]['teste'][0]['dados']` e `dados[0]['teste'][0]['uno']` (o primeiro retorna a string `"teste"` e o segundo retorna uma lista, cujo único elemento é o objeto que possui as chaves `"um"` e `"cores"`). E assim por diante.

Seguindo esse raciocínio é possível chegar nos valores que você precisa:

```py
print(dados[0]['teste'][0]['dados']) # teste
print(dados[0]['teste'][0]['uno'][0]['cores'][0]['preto']) # Preto
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.loads) do módulo [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) que é capaz de ler uma string contendo dados em formato JSON e convertê-la para uma estrutura de dados primitiva composta basicamente por `listas` e `dicionários`, veja só:

```
import json

JSON = """[
{
    "teste":[
        {
            "dados":"teste",
            "uno":[
                {
                    "um":"Teste",
                    "cores":[
                        {
                            "preto":"Preto",
                            "branco":"Branco"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
]"""

dados = json.loads(JSON)
print(dados)
```

Saída:

```
[{'teste': [{'uno': [{'cores': [{'branco': 'Branco', 'preto': 'Preto'}], 'um': 'Teste'}], 'dados': 'teste'}]}]
```

Acessando o conteúdo de **preto**:

```
print( dados[0]['teste'][0]['uno'][0]['cores'][0]['preto'] )
```

Acessando o conteúdo de **dados**:

```
print( dados[0]['teste'][0]['dados'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim:

```
import json 

json_str = """[
{
    "teste":[
        {
            "dados":"teste",
            "uno":[
                {
                    "um":"Teste",
                    "cores":[
                        {
                            "preto":"Preto",
                            "branco":"Branco"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]"""

json_list = json.loads(json_str)

print(json_list[0]['teste'][0]['dados'])
```