# Calcular data limite de trabalho

Tags: python, python-3.x, data

Tenho um projeto no qual o usuário dá um dia e um mês onde ele iria iniciar alguma tarefa e o programa deveria, baseado em algumas regras, retornar uma data final.

- Exemplo de regras: maximo de dias corridos = 90; excluir fins de semana e feriados

Esse é meu código atual, acredito que estou bem perdido, até tentei usar uma biblioteca de datas, mas sem sucesso.

```py
import json
import requests
from datetime import date

l_d = 90
l_h = 1000
n = 0
lista = []

p = int(input("Nº de Pessoas: "))
y = int(input("Ano: "))
d = int(input("Dia de Inicio: "))
m = int(input("Mês de Inicio: "))

y_str = str(y)

api1 = "https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&token=ZmVsaXBlLmEubWF6aWVyaUBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSZoYXNoPTczMDA3OTc0&ano="
api2 = "&estado=SP&cidade=Sao_Paulo"
url = api1 + y_str + api2

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

for x in json_data:
    feriados = json_data[n]["date"]
    n+=1
    novalista = lista.append(feriados)

#dm = "{}/{}/{}".format(d, m, y)

print("")
# print(lista[n-1]) # colocar [ e alguem nº aqui, da pra exibir a data correspondente a posição dentro da lista, começando pelo nº ZERO (0) que é a 1ª posição dentro da lista]
# while n > 0:
    # print("É feriado em SP no dia",lista[n-1])
    # n = n -1

data = ("{}/{}/{}").format(d, m, y)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

O JSON<sup>1</sup> retornado pela API é um array (pois está delimitado por `[]`), então ele é [convertido para uma lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) (ou seja, sua variável `json_data` é uma lista).

E a forma de percorrer os elementos de uma lista é simplesmente usar `for elemento in lista:`. A sua variável `n` não é necessária aqui, pois o `x` do seu primeiro `for` já será o elemento do array a cada iteração.

Outro detalhe é que [o método `append` **não** retorna outra lista](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016822), então atribuir o seu retorno em outra variável não é necessário. Apenas chame `append` na lista que você quer adicionar o elemento e pronto:

```
feriados = []
for x in json_data:
    feriado = x["date"]
    feriados.append(feriado)
```

Assim, você terá uma lista com os feriados. Repare que no *loop* eu troquei o nome da variável `feriados` (plural) por `feriado` (singular), pois ela representa apenas um único feriado. Já a variável `lista` possuía um nome genérico demais (é uma lista de que?), e troquei o nome dela para `feriados` (esse sim no plural), pois assim fica mais claro o que ela contém. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores para variáveis, funções, módulos, etc, ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) (eu só mantive o `x` do seu código original para você perceber que poderia usá-lo, em vez de ignorá-lo e usar o `n`, mas ele poderia ter outro nome também, como `elemento` ou `dados_feriado`, ou algo assim).

Obs: na verdade essa variável `feriado` nem é tão necessária assim, daria para fazer diretamente `feriados.append(x['date'])`.

---

Outra alternativa para o *loop* acima é usar a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052). A linha abaixo é equivalente ao `for` acima, produzindo a mesma lista contendo as datas do JSON:

```
feriados = [ dados_feriado['date'] for dados_feriado in json_data ]
```

Existe ainda outra alternativa, que é usar a [função `map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
feriados = list(map(lambda dados_feriado: dados_feriado['date'], json_data))
```

O primeiro parâmetro passado para `map` é um [*lambda*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda): uma função que será aplicada a cada elemento da lista. No caso, ela retorna o valor da chave `date`, e faz isso para cada elemento da lista. Como `map` retorna um [iterador](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), eu uso [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) para convertê-lo para uma lista.

---

#### Verificar se as datas estão na lista

Aqui tem um detalhe importante: conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052), **datas não têm formato**.

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "2 de janeiro de 1970", por exemplo, representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 2 do mês de janeiro do ano de 1970. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 02/01/1970 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 1/2/1970 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1970-01-02 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- Dois de janeiro de 1970 (em bom português)
- January 2<sup>nd</sup>, 1970 (em inglês)
- 1970年1月2日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

Dito isso, um JSON não define um tipo específico para datas, então na verdade a lista criada anteriormente não possui datas: ela possui **strings**, que representam datas em um formato específico (no caso, "dd/mm/aaaa"). Sabendo disso, podemos prosseguir.

---

Em Python, você pode usar o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) para trabalhar com datas. Como nesse caso você só está interessado no dia, mês e ano, e não se importa com o horário, pode usar a [classe `date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects). Exemplo:

```
ano = int(input("Ano: "))
mes = int(input("Mêsde Inicio: "))
dia = int(input("Dia de Inicio: "))
dt = date(ano, mes, dia)
```

Assim, a variável `dt` será a data correspondente ao dia, mês e ano informados.

Depois basta fazer um *loop* somando um dia a esta data (usando um [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) para isso), e verificando se a data é fim de semana ou feriado (e caso não seja, você considera esse dia na sua contagem).

Para verificar se é um fim de semana, basta usar o [método `weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday), que retorna valores entre zero (segunda-feira) e 6 (domingo). Ou seja, se o valor estiver entre 0 e 4, não é fim de semana.

Já para verificar se a data é feriado, não basta verificar se `dt` está contida na lista `feriados`. Lembre-se que datas não têm formato, e `dt` é um `date` (ou seja, um objeto que representa o conceito de uma data, **sem nenhum formato específico**), mas `feriados` é uma lista de strings (sendo que essas strings representam datas em um formato específico). Ou seja, para verificar se uma data está na lista, precisamos formatá-la para o mesmo formato em que as strings estão. Para isso, usamos o [método `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

Então o código ficaria assim:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

ano = int(input("Ano: "))
mes = int(input("Mês de Inicio: "))
dia = int(input("Dia de Inicio: "))
dt = date(ano, mes, dia)

contagem_dias = 0
while contagem_dias < 90:
    dt += timedelta(days=1)
    if dt.weekday() <= 4 and dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') not in feriados:
        contagem_dias += 1

print('data final:', dt)
```

O `while` vai somando um dia na data, e só incrementa o contador se não for fim de semana **e** se não for feriado.

---

#### E se mudar o ano?

A solução acima ainda é meio "ingênua", pois não considera o caso em que ano muda. Por exemplo, se você começa com uma data nos últimos meses do ano, ao contar 90 dias o resultado final será no ano seguinte, mas você só busca os feriados do ano atual. Então sugiro criar primeiro uma função que busca os feriados de determinado ano:

```
def buscar_feriados(ano):
    # faz o request para a API, passando o ano
    api1 = "https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&token=ZmVsaXBlLmEubWF6aWVyaUBob3RtYWlsLmNvbSZoYXNoPTczMDA3OTc0&ano="
    api2 = "&estado=SP&cidade=Sao_Paulo"
    url = api1 + str(ano) + api2

    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    return [ dados_feriado['date'] for dados_feriado in json_data ]
```

E depois você usa essa função no seu código. Primeiro você carrega os feriados do ano atual, e no `while` você verifica se o ano mudou (e caso tenha mudado, atualize a lista com os feriados deste ano):

```
dt = date(ano, mes, dia)
feriados = buscar_feriados(ano)

contagem_dias = 0
ano_atual = ano
while contagem_dias < 90:
    dt += timedelta(days=1)

    if dt.year != ano_atual: # mudou o ano
        feriados.extend(buscar_feriados(dt.year))
        ano_atual = dt.year

    if dt.weekday() <= 4 and dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') not in feriados:
        contagem_dias += 1

print('data final:', dt)
```

O método `extend` adiciona os elementos da lista retornada por `buscar_feriados` na lista `feriados`. Com isso, a lista de feriados é atualizada conforme o ano for mudando.

Por fim, eu sugiro rever esta API de feriados que você está usando, pois ela retorna coisas como "primeiro de abril" e "dia dos namorados" (12 de junho), que apesar de serem datas "especiais", não são necessariamente feriados (não no sentido de que as pessoas que normalmente trabalhariam neste dia não precisarão trabalhar). Mas aí acredito que esse tratamento já foge ao escopo da pergunta, pois "feriados" é um assunto mais complexo do que parece: tem que decidir se vai considerar feriados nacionais, estaduais e municipais, há "feriados" específicos dependendo do contexto (as seguradoras não costumam trabalhar no dia do securitário, o judiciário possui um calendário próprio, etc), há as "emendas" de feriado (se cai na quinta, você considera a sexta como dia útil ou também pula ela na contagem? - o código acima não "emenda" nenhum feriado), etc.

---

Outra alternativa seria criar a lista de feriados contendo instâncias de `date`, em vez de strings. Nesse caso, as strings teriam que ser convertidas para `date`, usando o [método `datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

# agora a lista contém instâncias de date em vez de strings
feriados = [ datetime.strptime(dados_feriado['date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date() for dados_feriado in json_data ]

contagem_dias = 0
dt = date(ano, mes, dia)
while contagem_dias < 90:
    dt += timedelta(days=1)
    if dt.weekday() <= 4 and dt not in feriados:
        contagem_dias += 1

print('data final:', dt)
```

No caso, `datetime.strptime` retorna um [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), então eu uso o [método `date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) para convertê-lo para um objeto `date`. Dessa forma, a lista `feriados` não contém mais strings, e sim instâncias de [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects). Sendo assim, no `while` eu não preciso mais converter as datas para string, e posso verificar diretamente se a lista `feriados` contém a data `dt`.

---

**1**: veja mais sobre a sintaxe JSON [aqui](http://json.org/), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396641/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369259/112052) e [aqui](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-13/como-ler-e-manipular-um-json).

Answer (score 0):

Esse API só passa os feriados mesmo?
Acho que poderia usar esse mesmo API para saber se é fim de semana ou não. Mas enfim.....

Utilizando a biblioteca datetime, você primeiro deve formatar a informação "data" que foi extraida do json para o mesmo formato do datetime (YYYY-MM-DD), pois irá facilitar nossa vida...
Agora para verificar o que você necessita:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
ano = input()
mes = input()
dia = input()
aux = 0
dt = datetime(ano, mes, dia)
while(aux < 90):
   if dt.weekday() > 4 or dt in feriado_lista:
      pass
   else:
      aux += 1
   dt_fim += timedelta(days=1) 

print(datetime(ano, mes, dia))
print(dt)
```

**Notas**
- *datetime.datetime.weekday():* Se retornar valor maior que 4 é final de semana.
- *datetime.timedelta():* Acrescenta um valor desjado do objeto datetime.

Comment: Infelizmente a API só literalmente passa os feriados e não achei nada + completo :/